# How to Filter Data by Week Number and Year

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter, formula, week-number

I have 3 columns with reference number in column A, a unique number in column B, and a further reference in column C.  Associated to each are figures which in a row which is in a column assigned to a week number and year.

On the second tab I have a search function which I would like to show me all the unique information in A:C, aligned to the search of a "Week Number" and "Year".

I have struggled with HLookups, Filters and Indexs and cannot figure out how to get this right.  I hope one of you geniuses can help me decipher this.

Please see link to google sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14mavbCIzIVQmYMkOOVl4cndhHlzp0wzfZJdSd7i189I/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `all the unique information`? Could you define it and show an example output?

Comment: @Argyll, sure, and apologies - tried to make it generic but see now that this is a problem.  Essentially the first "REF" is an internal contract number, the "unique identifier" is a container number and the "REF 2" is a storage facility.  The output I require is for the formula to give me "storage costs" for containers within a certain week of a year.  The output should just display the internal reference, container and storage facility and then sum the costs associated to that for the week and year I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try (but unclear on your expected header `sum of values` since Column_B is already a unique identifier):*

```js
=filter({Helper!A4:B,filter(Helper!D4:Y,Helper!D3:Y3=C3,Helper!D2:Y2=C4)},Helper!C4:C=C5)
```

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you - did not think of nesting a filter within a filter.  The only problem this has is that the first filter displays all the "sequence" iterations and not those that align to the week or year only.  However, I am sure I can adjust your formula to make it work.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you need further adjustment to the above formula, suggest you to add the expected output ***manually*** so that it gives a clear picture of what is it that you are expecting to see...